# How to restrict input in Excel to lower case letters, numbers and underscore only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Going off of some websites, I have tried to restrict excel cell entries to the following

1. Lower case letters
2. Numbers
3. Underscores

The way I do this by selecting a cell, clicking "Data Validation">"Custom" and inputing the below as an equation

```
=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(E10,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(E10))),1),"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_")))
```

However, it still allows for typing of upper case letters. Can someone please advise how to change the above Excel equation to restrict the inputing of upper case letters.

Comment: `SEARCH` and `FIND` do the same job, but one is case sensitive

Comment: [SEARCH, SEARCHB functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495): "The SEARCH and SEARCHB functions are not case sensitive. If you want to do a case sensitive search, you can use FIND and FINDB."

Comment: @AxelRichter I read the link on search and searchB, but what I could not find what the difference between the B and the non B version is.

Comment: @Forward Ed: In linked Microsoft article: "SEARCHB counts 2 bytes per character only when a [DBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBCS) language is set as the default language. Otherwise SEARCHB behaves the same as SEARCH, counting 1 byte per character." - So rtfm ;-).

Comment: @AxelRichter I need my prescription checked!